# Why the log dont shows the request info send by the API?

Tags: php, laravel

After a user made a payment the API the configured URL in the API backoffice. Its a GET request. The url configured in the backoffice is like:

```
 http://....ngrok.io/mbpay/notification-callback
```

So I have this route:

```
Route::get('/mbpay/notification-callback', [
    'uses' => 'PaymentController@notifications',
    'as'   =>'mb.notifications'
]);
```

And the method to log the result:

```
 public function notifications(Request $request)
    {
        Log::info('request info: ' . var_export($request->all(), true));
    }
}
```

But its not working, the log is not showing nothing, do you know what can be the issue?

Comment: Probably not hitting the right route, try adding dd() inside the function if nothing happens you are routing it wrong

Comment: Also you'll like to check your `LOG_LEVEL` variable in the `env` file to be sure its not greater than `debug` check: https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/doc/01-usage.md to understand. Actually, dd() is a better way to find out what's going on....

Comment: Thanks but with "dd()" how to check the results? Because the API sends a notification with some parameters. The notifications() is called when the API receives a payment notificaiton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things I´d suggest when routing is not working as expected.

- Remove bootstrap/cache/routes.php
- php artisan route:cache

For your specific case:

- Make sure notifications returns something as simple as a "hello"
- Does your ngrok response catches this hello response?

Comment: Thanks, in "bootstrap/cache/" there is no routes.php. How to check that if returns some text? Is also in the log?

Comment: Well, if your routing is working correctly ( by this I mean that you can navigate through /mbpay/notification-callback in your browser and receive a response ) you should see the log content as log you have specified correctly in your config/logging.php file